# Are GDB registers different from processor registers?

Tags: x86, gdb, cpu-registers

Is the $pc register of gdb different from eip register in x86 32 bit processor? There are four standard registers available in gdb like $pc. So if it is the same registers with different names then how the mapping is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$pc` in GDB is just an alias for `$EIP` on `ix86`, for `$RIP` on `x86_64`, for `$pc` on `ARM`, `MIPS` and `SPARC`, for `$ip` on `ia64`, etc.

> what about the other three registers? I mean $sp, $fp and $ps

What about them? On `ix86`, `$sp` is an alias for `$esp`, on `x86_64` it's an alias for `$RSP`, on `MIPS` it's an alias for `$r29`, etc.

The `$ps` is an alias for `$EFLAGS` on `ix86` and `x86_64`. There is no equivalent register on `MIPS`, so `$ps` doesn't map to anything there.

> if it is the same registers with different names then how the mapping is done

Inside GDB, there is a compiled-in one-to-one map.

> I didn't get the point about compiled-in one to one

There is *literally* a map inside GDB, that looks like this:

```
if current target is i*86
  if the user typed $pc return $eip
  else if the user typed $fp return $ebp else
  ...
else if current target is x86_64
  if the user typed $pc return $rip
  else if the user typed $fp return $rbp
  ...
```

(This isn't how it's actually implemented, but just an explanation of the one-to-one mapping.)

Comment: And what about the other three registers? I mean $sp, $fp and $ps. To which these registers are mapped? Also I didn't get the point about compiled-in one to one.

Comment: Thanks got my answer. But I think you forgot to mention the alias name of $fp

Comment: Can you please answer the alias name of $fp?

Comment: @Kaustav I left `$fp` as an exercise to the reader. It's actually *in the answer*, you just need to re-read it carefully.

Comment: Yeah got it this time. Thanks